# Getting error "Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled " when removing @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I would like to remove the @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties plugin as we are now targeting chrome 79 which supports class properties. I would imagine that removing this plugin shouldn't be a problem because we no longer need babel to transpile that code.

When I remove the plugin from the plugins section of the babelrc file, I am getting an error -

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js), ...
"Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled "
```

Relevant Package.json entries:

"@babel/core": "^7.0.0",

"@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",

"webpack": "4.40.0",

Here is my .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 79
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-styled-components"
  ]
}
```

Here is my webpack config, relevant loader configuration:

```
  {
    test: /\.(js(x)?|ts(x)?)$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Any help or insight would be appreciated.